# celebrate npm package with Nest Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, backend, nestjs

Is there some way to use [celebrate NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/celebrate) with [Nest Framework](https://nestjs.com/)? In the documentation they only refer to [class-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator), but although this has many advantages I have used with Express and other frameworks the celebrate middleware to validate the request. In the case of Nest, the middleware configuration is done in the app.module.ts file, but in others as [routing-controllers](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers) the decorator @UseBefore is used for the middleware in the controllers, that is why I would appreciate any explanation, example or documentation how to use this middleware with Nest. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

In a file dedicated to the validations create the `middleware` with the `scheme` to use by `celebrate` (this would be a simple example for an authentication):

```
import { celebrate, Joi } from 'celebrate';

export const authenticate = celebrate({
    headers: Joi.object().keys({
        client: Joi.string().required(),
        application: Joi.string().required(),
    }).unknown(),
    body: Joi.object().keys({
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        password: Joi.string().required(),
    }),
});
```

How to use it later? Import it in the module and apply it as a `middleware`, since `celebrate` returns a function of type `function (req, res, next)`:

```
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer, RequestMethod } from '@nestjs/common';
// Others imports ...
import { authenticate } from './validations/authenticate.validation';


@Module({
    imports: [ // Your imports... ],
    controllers: [ // Your controllers... ],
    providers: [ // Your providers... ],
})
export class AuthenticationModule implements NestModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        // Validate Login.
        consumer.apply(authenticate).forRoutes({ path: 'security/login', method: RequestMethod.POST });
    }
}
```

The `path` defined in the configuration must obviously match the `endpoint` of the controller:

```
import {
    Body,
    Post,
    Headers,
    Controller,
} from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('security')
export class AuthenticationController {

    @Post('login')
    async authenticate(
        @Body('email') email: string,
        @Body('password') password: string,
        @Headers('application') application: string): Promise<any> {

        // Autenticate user
    }
}
```

References:

https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware

https://www.npmjs.com/package/celebrate